# berichten über vs. berichten

Tags: meaning, verb, preposition

Ich kann den Unterschied zwischen *berichten* und *berichten über* nicht verstehen. Zum Beispiel, was ist der Unterschied zwischen den folgenden Sätzen:

> Patienten mit Angina pectoris berichten über Schmerzen hinter dem Brustbein.
>
> Patienten mit Angina pectoris berichten Schmerzen hinter dem Brustbein.

Comment: Was sagt denn Dein Wörterbuch über _über_?

Comment: Mein Wörterbuch sagt nichts darüber. Es gibt nur Beispiele, aber ich kann den Unterschied nicht wirklich verstehen. Ich sehe, es gibt keinen Unterschied aber da bin ich mir nicht sicher.

Comment: Ich interessiere mich besonders für diesen Zusammhang: Der Patient berichtet etwas und etwas (Symptome) v.s Der Patient berichtet über etwas und etwas (Symptome)

Comment: Es gäbe auch noch die Variante _berichten von_.

Comment: Kleiner Hinweis: *Schmerzen* ist hier ein Substantiv und wird großgeschrieben

Comment: Ich tendiere dazu zu vermuten, dass das erste eher impliziert, dass Details der Schmerzen im Vordergrund stehen, während das zweite eher Verwendung findet, wenn der Fakt alleine das ist, was ausgesagt werden soll. "Kuriere berichten über den Einfall der Hunnen." (Kindern wurden die Köpfe abgetrennt). "Kuriere berichten den Einfall der Hunnen" (woraufhin der König die Koffer packte und auf die Bahamas floh). Aber zu vage für eine Antwort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Üblicherweise berichtet man *von* oder *über* etwas:

- Patienten berichten *von* Schmerzen in der Brust.
- Patienten berichten *über* Schmerzen in der Brust.

Ist das Etwas eine Handlung, die man durch eine Verbalphrase ausdrücken möchte, wie etwa dass Schmerzen *aufgetreten sind*, dann kann man einen Dass-Satz oder etwas Ähnliches verwenden:

- Patienten berichten, *dass* Schmerzen in der Brust *aufgetreten seien*.
- Patienten berichten, es *seien* Schmerzen *aufgetreten*.

Das Verb *berichten* kann auch im Sinne von *vortragen* verwendet werden. In diesem Falle entfällt die Präposition. Ich vermute, ohne es belegen zu können, dass diese Verwendung von *berichten* aus dem Englischen stammt (to report data); man findet sie häufig in wissenschaftlichen Kontexten, wo Ergebnisse, Erfahrungen und dergleichen *vorgetragen* werden:

- Patienten berichten ihre Schmerzerfahrungen.

   <sup>(= Patienten tragen ihre Schmerzerfahrungen vor.)</sup>

In diesem Sinne ist „Patienten berichten Schmerzen in der Brust“ stilistisch unschön, denn die Schmerzen selbst können nicht vorgetragen werden.

Comment: Du meinst "*von* **oder** *über*", oder? (statt "über *über*")

Comment: @amadeusamadeus, oh ja. Danke für den Hinweis.